# detect change in component grid when a checkbox status in a headerComponent is changed

Tags: angular, ag-grid

i'm new on ag-grid and i have this grid containing one column.

```
column3=[
    {
        field: 'useselected',
        headerName: 'Users selected', 
        sortable: true, 
        filter: 'agTextColumnFilter', 
        
        checkboxSelection: true,
        headerComponentFramework:UserSelectedHeaderComponent,
        headerComponentFrameworkParams:{
            TaChecked:true,
            UwChecked:false
        },
        
        
        
        
    }
]
```

this is my grid:

```
<ag-grid-angular

style="width: 202px; height: 500px;"
class="ag-theme-alpine"
[columnDefs]="column3"
[rowData]="row4"
rowSelection="multiple"
[gridOptions]="gridOption"
(ComponentStateChangedEvent)="ComponentStateChanged($event)"
(selectionChanged)="getSelectedRows()"
>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

and this is my custom component for the header:

```
@Component({
    selector:'app-user-selected-header',
    templateUrl:'./user-selected-header.component.html',
    styleUrls:['./user-selected-header.component.scss'],
})
export class UserSelectedHeaderComponent {
displayHeader:any
TaChecked:boolean
UwChecked:boolean
constructor(){}

agInit(params){
    this.displayHeader=params.column.colDef.headerName
    this.TaChecked=params.column.colDef.headerComponentFrameworkParams.TaChecked
    this.UwChecked=params.column.colDef.headerComponentFrameworkParams.UwChecked
    console.log('params',params)
}
}
```

and my html code for the headercomponent:

```
<div class="ag-cell-label-container" role="presentation" style="display:flex;flex-direction:column">
                
    <div ref="eLabel" class="ag-header-cell-label" style="height:48px" role="presentation">
    <span ref="eText" class="ag-header-cell-text" role="columnheader">{{displayHeader}}</span>
    
    </div>
    <div style="flex-direction: row;display: flex;justify-content: space-evenly; align-self: stretch;">  
    
    
   
    <li><input  name="radioSelect"  type="checkbox" [checked]="TaChecked" [(ngModel)]="TaChecked">TA</li>
    <li><input name="radioSelect"  type="checkbox" [checked]="UwChecked" [(ngModel)]="UwChecked">UW</li>
    </div>
    <div style="height:48px" class="ag-floating-filter-input">
    <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
```

right now if the user click on a checkbox these two params are changing values

```
headerComponentFrameworkParams:{
            TaChecked:true,
            UwChecked:false
        },
```

and i'm able to see theme changing values in the UserSelectedHeaderComponent component but i'm not able to detecte those changes in the grid component.
please if anyone know how can i achieve that.

Comment: please include code for `getSelectedRows` as that is the method that detects row selection. there might be your error.

Answer (score 0):

When using the `headerComponentFramework` the default props you get in addition to the params you pass via `headerComponentFrameworkParams` have the current `gridApi` (as `api`) in them.

In your custom header component when your checkbox is clicked you can do the following :

```js
gridApi.forEachNode(node => {
      node.setSelected(true);
    });
```

that will loop over all the visible rows in the grid and set them to `selected`.